# git pull from a github repository fork gives conflicts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

I have forked rails `git://github.com/rails/rails.git` at github. My forked repository is at `git://github.com/waseem/rails.git`. I want to test out some patches submitted by other users to rails mainline. Lets say I want to test out code in `migration_status` branch at `git://github.com/joelmoss/rails.git`.

Lets say I

`master $ git remote add joelmoss git://github.com/joelmoss/rails.git`. and

`master $ git remote add mainline git://github.com/rails/rails.git`.

I have been pulling from rails mainline into my master.

`master $ git pull mainline master`

According to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/contributing_to_ruby_on_rails.html#testing-patches I should create a local topic branch and pull in changes from `joelmoss/migration_status`. So I,

`master $ git checkout -b migration_status` Create a local topic branch.

And when I do:

`migration_status $ git pull joelmoss migration_status`

I get a large number of conflicts. I also tried `migration_status $ git pull --rebase joelmoss migration_status` but I still get conflicts.

In the case of `pull --rebase`, I think (correct if wrong), git is trying to apply my local changes on top of changes fetched from `joelmoss/migration_status`. Ideally it should do the opposite. To consider this option, I did following.

`master $ git fetch joelmoss`

`master $ git checkout -b joel_migration_status joelmoss/migration_status` and

`joel_migration_status $ git rebase master` it still gave me lots of conflicts.

How do I pull in patches submitted to one of my local topic branches w/o getting conflicts? I can not resolve those conflicts as I do not know much about what code to keep what not to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, it looks like `joelmoss/migration_status` is based off of 3.1.0, which split from `mainline/master` back in May.  So if you merge you're trying to reconcile 4 months worth of development by everyone, in branches that appear to never have been intended to merge.

What you want to do is base your local changes on 3.1 as well.  That doesn't guarantee to remove all conflicts, but at least it should be ones you are aware of because it's code you changed directly.

```
git checkout -b master-3-1 master
git rebase --onto joelmoss/migration_status mainline/master master-3-1
```

Comment: Thanks Karl. I do not know how I missed the fact the `joelmoss/migration_status` was based off of 3.1.0.